# Create a randomly connected set of nodes?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to write a function, `generate_labyrinth()`, that creates a fixed number of randomly connected nodes. Each node is connected with three other nodes.

Here is what I have now:

`labyrinth.h`:

```
#ifndef LABYRINTH_H
#define LABYRINTH_H     
// node
class Room {
public:
    Room () 
        : room_number(0), left_door(nullptr),
        center_door(nullptr), right_door(nullptr) { }

    // data member
    int room_number;
    // pointers to other nodes
    Room* left_door;
    Room* center_door;
    Room* right_door;
};
//================================================= 

class Labyrinth {
public:
    Labyrinth (int s) : size(s) { generate_labyrinth (); }
private:
    // number of nodes
    int size;

    // root node
    Room* entrance;

    // Helper functions
    int random_number (int from, int to);
    int random_number_without_i (int min, int max, int i);

    // Initialiazation function
    void generate_labyrinth ();
};
#include "labyrinth.cpp"
#endif
```

`labyrinth.cpp`:

```
// Class Labyrinth member implementations
int Labyrinth::random_number (int min, int max) {
    static bool seed_initialized = false;
    if (!seed_initialized) {
        seed_initialized = true;
        srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    }
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min; 
}

int Labyrinth::random_number_without_i (int min, int max, int i) {
    int res = random_number(min, max);
    while (res == i){
        res = random_number(min, max);
    }
    return res;
}

void Labyrinth::generate_labyrinth () {
    // create "size" number of nodes
    entrance = new Room[size];    

    // initialize Room (node) data members
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        entrance[i].room_number = i;
    }
    // connect each room with three others
    int first_room = 1;  
    int last_room = size - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        // avoid connecting a room with itself            
        int left_goes_to = random_number_without_i (first_room, last_room, i);
        int center_goes_to = random_number_without_i (first_room, last_room, i);
        int right_goes_to = random_number_without_i (first_room, last_room, i);

        entrance[i].left_door = (&entrance[left_goes_to]);
        entrance[i].center_door = (&entrance [center_goes_to]);
        entrance[i].right_door = (&entrance [right_goes_to]);;
    }
    // TEST IF NODES POINT TO EACH OTHER
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (entrance[i].left_door == nullptr || entrance[i].center_door == nullptr ||
            entrance[i].right_door == nullptr) {
            std::cout <<"Uninitialized pointer value\n";
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

`main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "labyrinth.h"
//=================================================  

int main()
{
    int cave_size = 20;
    Labyrinth cave(cave_size);
}
```

It appears that after the node initialization in `generate_labyrinth ()` the three pointers, `left_room`, `center_room`, `right_room` remain uninitialized, i.e. the output I get is :

> `Uninitialized pointer value`

### Questions:

Why aren't the pointers in the nodes initialized?

Is there another way to generate a randomly connected set of nodes?

---

<sup>**Note:** I'm not using an `insert()` function as the number of nodes is fixed and determined during the construction of the data structure.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate connections for `first_room` to `last_room`, which are rooms `1` to `size-1`.

```
// connect each room with three others
int first_room = 1;  
int last_room = size - 1;
for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
```

But when you check the connections you start with room `0` (probably supposed to be the entrance itself).

```
// TEST IF NODES POINT TO EACH OTHER
for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! Yes, the node with index `0`  is supposed to be the entrance. I will match the loops' indexes and run a quick check.

Comment: You are correct, that was it! I will leave the question open (for a bit more) for anyone who wishes to comment on the second question (alternative methods)